# Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc

I've got the following class in my Spring Boot app:

```
@Configuration
public class JDBCTokenConfig {

    ...

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String dbDriverClassName;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
        return dataSource;
    }
```

I've also got the following in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

In my application.properties I have:

```
...
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Yet I'm seeing the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]
```

Is this the correct the drive class path? Or anything else?

Comment: You don't need dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName). Just comment it out along with the @Value

Comment: Thanks. I tried removing setDriverClassName and it seems to work fine too. That's great, less code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

Spring uses the following preconfigured versions for dependencies when a version is not explicitly provided in the pom.xml:
 https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions

Here the following version of mysql-connector-java will be used . **5.1.47**

For  mysql-connector-java v**5.1.47** the correct driver class is **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

You could also provide the dependency with version to use the latest driver : **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have added latest version of mysql connector in pom as you mention. However, I still gets `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver]` error. 
Here is connection code: 
`DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://xx.x.x.x:x/xxx");
dataSource.setUsername("xxx");
dataSource.setPassword("xxx!");
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
SqlRowSet sqlRowSet = template.queryForRowSet("SELECT * FROM dbo.xxx;")`

Comment: is the Driver name a typo ? com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver , is the correct Driver class name

Comment: future readers : "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" seems to go hand in hand with this dialect "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect". at least for '8.0.21'